I need React draggable-resizable library with drag only on certain part of element - "react-moveable"
I'm looking for some React library, that will make my <div> draggable only at certain part of element, resizable.
I have found "react-moveable" library that makes my elements draggable and resizable, but I need my user to be able to work in the draggable component, not just move it around.
Anyone has any idea how to do it, or can advice any other library that is able doing that?
Thank you for any advice!

You might want to check out react-rnd, which seems to meet your requirements
